# How to read json file from blob storage using Azure Functions Blob Trigger with C#

Tags: azure-functions

using Azure Function with Blob Trigger. How do I read the JSON file. In the sample it reads only the length. Should I use Stream or CloudBlockBlob ? I need to deseralize json using c#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like the below will do the trick.

```
[FunctionName("BlobTriggerCSharp")]        
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("demo/{name}")] Stream stream, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        var person = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, typeof(Person));

        // Do something with person.
    }
}
```

See Json.Net docs for more details - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can bind as a **string**, and then the SDK will read the contents for you.  Then you can convert to JSON.

```
[FunctionName("BlobTriggerCSharp")]        
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("demo/{name}")] string contents) 
{
   var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(contents); 
}
```

You could also bind to byte[] to get the byte contents.

Comment: It'll be more efficient to use streams than passing around chunks of `byte[]` or `string`